# Negative lookbehind/ahead assertions in Linux less pager (or vim)

Tags: vim, regular-expression, less

I want to find all instances of "index" not followed by .php in a log using `less`.   `/index(?!\.php)` does not work.  Is this possible? What is the regex for less and vim (do they differ?).  Is this not possible with these application's respective regex libraries?

Comment: For the why part, see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `vim`, you can do like this:

```
/index\(\.php\)\@!
```

For more details, in command mode, try `:h \@`:

```
\@!     Matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match at the
        current position. /zero-width {not in Vi}
        Like '(?!pattern)" in Perl.
        Example                 matches
        foo\(bar\)\@!           any "foo" not followed by "bar"
        a.\{-}p\@!              "a", "ap", "aap", "app", etc. not immediately
                                followed by a "p"
        if \(\(then\)\@!.\)*$   "if " not followed by "then"
```

Comment: Beautiful! Any idea for less?  This doesn't work in less.  I wish regex behavior was PCRE everywhere, but alas it isn't.

Comment: Also note the syntax for **negativ lookbehind**: `\@<!`

Comment: It goes with saying that you need to put the negative look*behind* before the pattern. An example: `\(some\)\@<!thing` Will match `thing` and `everything` and `nothing`, but not `something`.

Answer (score 8):

`(?!\.php)` is a perl regexp operator. `less` generally uses the system's POSIX regexp API, so typically GNU extended regular expressions on a GNU system, `vim` uses `vim` regular expressions.

In `vim`, as already shown by cuonglm, the equivalent of `index(?!\.php)` would be `index\(\.php\)\@!` or `\vindex(\.php)@!`.

For `less`, at compile time, you can choose the regex library/API and as a result the regex type to use:

> ```
>     --with-regex={auto,gnu,pcre,posix,regcmp,re_comp,
>                     regcomp,regcomp-local,none}
>         Select a regular expression library  auto
> ```

By default though, `less` will use POSIX `regcomp` with REG_EXTENDED, so you'll get the extended regular expressions of your system, so typically something similar as with `grep -E`.

In GNU extended regexp, there's no equivalent look behind or look ahead operator.

You could do it the hard way:

```
index($|[^.]|\.($|([^p]|p($|([^h]|h($|[^p]))))))
```

With `less`, you could possibly use the `&` key to filter out the lines containing `index.php` (`&!index\.php`), and then search for `index` (`/index`). (you'd still miss the other instances of `index` that appear on a line also containing `index.php`).

Comment: I think what regex library which `less` uses is depended on compiled time.

Comment: @Gnouc, you're right, it even now supports PCRE it seems.

Comment: Yeah, we can check if `less` uses `PCRE` by parsing output of `ldd $(which less)`. But with other library, do you know any way to check?

Comment: @Gnouc, it prints the name of the regex library with `less --version`.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and with `less --verion`, it only prints `less 444` along with Copyright.

Comment: @Gnouc, yes, it looks like it's only included when explicitly specified at compile time. So if you see nothing, that means less was built with the default.